# NHibernate Collection Mapping - Read Only Properties

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, field

I have the following class

```
public class Person
{
    private IList<Person> _children;

    public IEnumerable<Person> Children { get; }

    public void AddChild(Person child)
    {
        // Some business logic and adding to the internal list
    }
}
```

What changes would I have to make for NHibenrate to be able to persist the Child collection (apart from making everything virtual, I know that one).

Do I have to add a setter to the children property which does something like a `_children.Clear(); _children.AddRange(value)`.  Currently the model expresses my intent quite nicely but I'm not sure how much alteration is need for NH to be able to help me out with persistence.

Comment: That may just work as is, depending on your mapping.  Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate is able to map private fields. Access and naming strategies are discussed in the [property](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property) section of the reference documentation.

Making your public members virtual is required for *proxies* to work. These will usually be runtime-generated subclasses of your entity classes.

In this example mapping the field `_children` will be `Children` in HQL and Criteria queries.

```
<class name="Person" table="person">
    <bag name="Children" access="field.camelcase-underscore">
        <key column="parentid" />
        <one-to-many class="Person" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

Comment: awesome, thanks very much.  I didn't know it could grab fields too!